# NSMenu not calling delegates menuHasKeyEquivalent:

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsmenu

I did setup a menu and assigned a delegate

```
- (void)constructAndDisplayMenu {

    NSMenu * menu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@""];

    {
        NSMenuItem * item = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"1" action:@selector(menuItemPressed:) keyEquivalent:@""];
        [menu addItem:item];
    }
    {
        NSMenuItem * item = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"2" action:@selector(menuItemPressed:) keyEquivalent:@""];
        [menu addItem:item];
    }
    {
        NSMenuItem * item = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"3" action:@selector(menuItemPressed:) keyEquivalent:@""];
        [menu addItem:item];
    }

    [menu popUpMenuPositioningItem:nil atLocation:NSMakePoint(2,2) inView:self];

    self.menu = menu;
    menu.delegate = self;

}
```

The menu gets showed up, and i get delegate callbacks like `menuDidClose:` but i don't get a call to `menuHasKeyEquivalent:forEvent:target:action:`

```
- (BOOL)menuHasKeyEquivalent:(NSMenu*)menu forEvent:(NSEvent*)event target:(id*)target action:(SEL*)action {

    NSLog(@"%@", event);

    return NO;
}
```

When typing to keyboard, the NSMenu changes the highlighted item automatically, but no callback on delegate is done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `menuHasKeyEquivalent:forEvent:target:action:` method works for the application's menu bar and not the contextual menus.
And even if a menu from the application's menu bar is open while you are using your shortcut key it won't get called.

Its behavior is not clearly documented but it was briefly mentioned in [WWDC 2010 Session 145](http://asciiwwdc.com/2010/sessions/145).